# Simulate vehicle in heightmap terrain issue

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, everyone. My problem is that whenever i try to insert my car into the terrain (made from heigtmap), it suddently jump off the terrain to very high and then fall down outside the terrain.

I tried a lot but could not figure out the cause. Could you help me? Thanks.

My terrain world:  [click here](https://github.com/tynguyen/my_simulation/blob/master/cart_demo_insert_good.world)

My car model: [click here](https://github.com/tynguyen/my_simulation/blob/master/model.sdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6160/simulate-vehicle-in-heightmap-terrain-issue/) by [TyNguyen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/745/tynguyen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TyNguyen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/745/tynguyen/) on 2014-05-08**:
Thanks to the suggestion of #nkoenig, i solved the problem. Here is the simple thing that i did:
In sdf model, set the pose of the model so that its initial z > the height of a point on terrain surface (on which i put/insert my car)
Then, i just need to run simulation and insert my car onto the the terrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem could be that the car starts in the middle of the terrain. Gazebo will then correct for this by pushing the car up.

Could you try the following:

1. Pause the simulator.
2. Insert your car.
3. Move your car so that it starts a bit above the heightmap.
4. unpause the simulator.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TyNguyen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/745/tynguyen/) on 2014-05-07**:
Thanks. I tried to follow your instruction but it does not work.  When i pause the simulator and insert the car, the car does not appear (maybe, it is underneath the terrain's surface). Then, because i could not move it as you said, it jump off the ground again after i resume the simulator.
Does the setting poses in car sdf matter?
However, things such as utility_cart can be inserted normally (of course, they also jump off the ground but not much, so that, they can stay till on the ground).

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-05-09**:
If you can't see the inserted model, you can still select it using the model-list widget on the left. You can also make the terrain transparent by right-clicking on the terrain. Setting the pose in SDF does matter.

**Comment by [TyNguyen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/745/tynguyen/) on 2014-05-14**:
Thanks, nkoenig. I got it done after changing pose in car sdf ( just let z > the height of the terrain, for my case, it is 10m.)

**Comment by [TyNguyen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/745/tynguyen/) on 2014-05-14**:
Btw i'm concerning how to build a slope road with a given steep angle. What i'm doing now: use Matlab to create a matrix with row element's value proportional to its height(same in a collumn). Then, i normalize the whole elements in matrix = dividing them by the max value of all elements so that they are all in between 0 and 1 => Printing out this matrix to .png file => terrain file.
=>Insert this terrain file into heightmap.world.
Is there any other method? & grey value of 1=? m in height?